# How to make python program ".py" executable?

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, executable

I need to make a py program run on command just by name
I can do that in by put the executable in /usr/bin/executable_program

yes. I know I can make it by:

```
chmod +x file.py
./file.py
```

I just want when I write the program name "executable_program" in terminal it runs
without the "./" and the ".py"

Thank you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I just want when I write the program name "executable_program" in
>   terminal it runs without the "./" and the ".py"

You need to do the following things:

1. Add the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the top of your file, `#!/usr/bin/python`
2. Make the file executable `chmod +x foo.py`
3. Move it to somewhere that is in your `$PATH`, for example `/usr/local/bin`

To get rid of the `.py`, simply rename the file: `sudo cp foo.py /usr/local/bin/foo`

```
burhan@sandbox:~/pytemp$ cat foo.py
#!/usr/bin/python
print('Hello World!')
burhan@sandbox:~/pytemp$ chmod +x foo.py
burhan@sandbox:~/pytemp$ sudo cp foo.py /usr/local/bin/foo
burhan@sandbox:~/pytemp$ foo
Hello World!
```

Comment: can't I crypt the script so no one can read it?!
That's also one of the best advantages of the executables :)

Comment: That's an entirely different question.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a directory in your home, for example:

```
$ mkdir ~/bin
```

Then add that directory to PATH variable in your `.bash_profile` with your favorite editor:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH
```

and then save the changes.

Now, open a new terminal and put your file in `~/bin`. After that, you can run your file without using `./` before it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your program to your path.

If you just export PATH=$PATH:. at the command line it will only last for the length of the session though.

If you want to change it permanently add export PATH=$PATH:. to your ~/.bashrc file (just at the end is fine)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/how-can-i-make-a-program-executable-from-everywhere

Answer (score 0):

I give you a example, write "test" file like this, not end with ".py".
The first comment line is your python interpreter path:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
print 'helloworld'
```

Then chmod 711 test;

Then export your test file path to $PATH(system path);

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH
```

Finally you can run test like this :

`test`